# How to use a loop in python to return elements of an array into a given set?

Tags: python, loops

For each index of a sorted array i = 1,...,N in this new array I want to find all indexes j such that xj is in the set (xi-5, xi+5).

```
x= np.array([1,2,2,3,4,6,7,9])
n=len(x)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if x[i] - 5 < x[j] and x[i] + 5 > x[j]:
            print(j)
```

So for this array example I gave, when i=0, x=1. So it should return [1,2,3,4] because they are all in (x_1-5, x_1+5). Then when i=1, x=2, and should return [0,2,3,4,5] and so on. I should get N arrays.

But, the output gives me

```
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 6 7 5 6 7
```

I don't know how I can implement this and I think the problem is `for j in x` since it is the same as the first loop. In my eyes, it says for every i, if any xj is in (xi-5,xi+5) then return the jth element. But, I want to return N sets.

Comment: try x= bubbleSort(np.array([1,4,7,2,3,9,2,6]))  and let us know

Comment: what are you defining as a subscript in this context?

'For i in x' and 'For j in x' are the same thing?

Comment: Also `for i in x` returns the elements of array x, not the indices. You would want `for i in range(len(x))`

Comment: @pippo1980 IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8..

Comment: @SuperHanz98 Yes I agree, but I wonder how I can interpret comparing different elements of an array in code? I want to go through each i in x and check if there is any xj in that set.

Comment: @Jia [1,4,7,2,3,9,2,6] is a list not an array change the code or the title (try: >>> print(type([1,4,7,2,3,9,2,6]))
<class 'list'>
>>>

Comment: What output do you expect for your sample input ` [1,4,7,2,3,9,2,6]`? And, your question says e.g. xi-5 - do you mean (xi)-5 or x(i-5]?

Comment: @barny I want to return N sets. if x_2 and x_3 is in (x_1-5, x_1+5) then I want to return S(1) = {2,3}, and repeat for each i. And i mean (x_i) - 5

Comment: Be specific; edit into your question exactly what output that you want for the input you provide `[1,4,7,2,3,9,2,6]` - simplify it if that makes it easier to show what you expect . If you can't show something to match, how is anyone to know if thyey've guessed right?

Comment: @barny You're right, is it clearer now in my question?

Comment: Err, no. Ditch the bubblesort code that's not relevant to your real question - start from a sorted list. How many sets do you expect from that list, and what are they? Like I say, if needed simplify the (sorted) input list so you cna show some real examples.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your indexes that way is probably what is confusing you.

If you want to access an index that is `n-2` then you have to index it that way.

What you are doing is accessing the nth index of your list and then subtracting or adding 2 from the value that you accessed.

```
x[i]
```

returns whatever value is at position `i` in the list.

```
x[i-2]
```

will return whatever value is at position `i-2`.

Also you will need to account for the fact that subtracting any number from your index variable will cause your resulting index to be out of bounds if the resulting index is greater than the length of the list - 1 or less than 0.

If you are looking for duplicates the best way is to sort first then compare neighbors.

```
for i in x:
  if x[i] == x[i+1]:
    print i;
```

Subsetting is done like this: `x[i-2:i+2]`

So to divide into n sets of 2 elements you would:

```
n=2
for i in x:
  if i+n < len(x):
    return x[i:i+n];
```

To divide into n sets of equal number of elements you would:

```
n = // Some arbitrary number.
j = int(len(x) / n);
for i in x:
  if i+j < len(x):
    return x[i:i+j];
```

Comment: So to conclude, i need to use only one loop (for i in x) and then use an additional if statement if when i add/subtract 5 it is outside of the bounds?

Comment: Don't forget to accept if this answer helped you.

Comment: Take a look at my edit regarding subsetting.

Comment: Went ahead and tested those loops. Seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your clarity on subsettings. Also, why equal elements? If only one value is 5 away from x_1 then the first set should have 1 element. Then if 6 elements are within 5 of x_2, then the second set should be 6 elements. So, would that require a different method, such as using a different n for each j?

Comment: Thats not even close to how your question reads. But my answer will still serve as the foundation for your needs. You just need to tweak how you want to determine the resulting set. I offered 2 ways as an example. All you should have to do is add your test to find your start and end point to slice out your subset. Make sense?